# When registering for Java events, are duplicate listeners typically allowed?

Tags: java, events, event-handling

Should an *addListener* method check for duplicate registrations when called? If so, what should happen when a duplicate is found?

```
final public class exampleCanFire {
    public void addFooListener(FooListener listener) {
      // Before adding listener to private list of listeners, should I check for duplicates?
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I don't know the answer, from a library design perspective surely the only consistent thing for the library to do is to register all listeners (duplicates included)? Otherwise, if two different subsystems by chance registered the same listener, then the first to deregister it would mess up the other subsystem -- correct?

Comment: It would mess up just as much as receiving every event twice because someone else re-registers your listener.

Comment: @Zed: Yes, but I'd argue that that is the fault of the person who carelessly combined the two subsystems. It must be the responsibility of the person who combines unrelated "peer" subsystems to know how they will interact -- since the alternative is for every subsystem to know how to interact with every other unrelated "peer" subsystem that currently exists or may exist in the future, and that's not viable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preference is to store them in a `List` and not check for duplicates.  Some advantages of this approach:

- Listeners are notified in a deterministic order and could potentially mark events as "consumed" causing them not to propagate to subsequent listeners.
- One can use the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` implementation, which allows a listener to remove itself during a notification callback without a `ConcurrentModificationException` being thrown (this is **very important** and is a classic gotcha when writing event oriented code).

Comment: The first point is entirely valid but on the 2nd point there is a CopyOnWriteArraySet available now too, which could potentially be used instead. But yeah, using Lists would still probably be the best option, making sure one doesnt' register duplicate listeners should be up to the client

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a specified behaviour for detecting duplicate listeners. I would say, unless you're writing an event handling framework it's probably better not to bother checking. If a class registers itself as a listener twice, it's a bug in the calling code and not in the observable object.

If you did want to do something I'd just suggest throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` stating the message that you cannot register the same listener twice.

Answer (score 0):

Store them in a Set, and propagate whatever the Set's response is:

```
Set<FooListener> listeners = new HashSet<FooListener>();

public boolean addFooListener(FooListener listener) {
  return listeners.add(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If found using Lists to be a lot slower than using the methods recommended by JAVA. My guess is JAVA's methods have a more direct interaction with memory, or something. Regardless, I agree with j_random_hacker in that you should know what calls what when and subsequently take the risk of duplicate listeners messing up eachothers resulting actions, but that's why we test our programs, isn't it ;-)