# When designing an event, is it a good idea to prevent listeners from being added twice?

Tags: events, event-handling

I am creating an event-based API where a user can subscribe to an event by adding listener objects (as is common in Java or C#).  When the event is raised, all subscribed listeners are invoked with the event information.

I initially decided to prevent adding an event listener more than once.  If a listener is added that already exists in the listener collection, it is not added again.  However, after thinking about it some more, it doesn't seem that most event-based structures actually prevent this.  Was my initial instinct wrong?  I'm not sure which way to go here.  I guess I thought that preventing addition of an existing listener would help to avoid a common programming error.  Then again, it could also hide a bug that would lead to code being run multiple times when it shouldn't.

Comment: Seems like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321296/when-registering-for-java-events-are-duplicate-listeners-typically-allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate the answers that have been given, but I think I will just go with preventing the same listener from being added more than once.  Java's Observable behaves this way, and I am using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` as the backing collection for the listeners which already has this available (`addIfAbsent()`).  It just seems less likely that someone would really wish to add the same listener multiple times, and it is simple to achieve the same behavior by either creating another listener or using iteration within the same listener.  I can understand the arguments for allowing duplicates (hence my doubts), but not strongly enough to change it.

Answer (score 2):

I would *guess* that most event systems just don't bother. It requires some effort to detect and block duplicates, and only very (very) rarely someone will accidentally try to ad an event more than once. Doing so on purpose is also rare but it can be valid.

So why block a rare but valid usage to prevent an even rarer error?

In short, I think that your "common programming error" isn't very common.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Henk, but then again, it's simpler to unregister a callback if there is only one of it. Otherwise you either have to specify that the last or first one will be removed, or it's arbitrary. Java's `Observable` class works this way, if an `Observer` is already in the list, `addObserver` with that `Observer` is a no-op. Then again, in my Python code I just remove the last copy of the observer from the list, and allow duplicates, I've just never found a good use case that depends on either strategy.

Comment: I had forgotten about Observable.  I guess it can go either way, then.